# MySQL: Procedure Loops, but only inserts once

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GenerateCharges2`()
BEGIN
Declare sumFunding LONG;
Declare done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
Declare invoiceCharge LONG;
Declare agencyID INT;
declare invoiceID int;
Declare fundingID INT;
Declare amountOfFunding LONG;
Declare getInvoiceData CURSOR For select invoices.idInvoices, invoices.idAgencies, invoices.InvoiceAmount, fundings.FundingBalance, fundings.idfundings from invoices 
inner join agencies on invoices.idAgencies = agencies.idAgencies
inner join fundings on  agencies.idAgencies = fundings.IdAgencies
where processed =0
group by invoices.idInvoices;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;


open getInvoicedata;
ze_loop: Loop
Fetch getInvoiceData into invoiceID, agencyID, invoiceCharge, amountOfFunding, fundingID;
if done then leave ze_loop;
end if;
if amountOfFunding > invoiceCharge then 
insert into charges VALUES (invoiceCharge, invoiceID, fundingID);
end if;
end loop;
close getInvoiceData;   
END
```

My issue is that if you were to insert a select statement, it runs a proper amont of times. However, the insert statement only inserts once with sample data. In every case, amnountOfFunding is ALWAYS greater than invoiceCharge. Desired results is to have all inserts happen for rows fetched.

Comment: Have you considered [`INSERT ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html)?

Comment: I am confused by your last two sentences, why not just remove the comparison between the two values?

Comment: Never heard of that before. New to MySQL/SQL. Where would I go about putting this statement?

Comment: @Ueerdo I do not want records made if amountOfFunding is < invoiceCharge?

Comment: @DefaultDefault: Your entire procedure is equivalent to `INSERT INTO charges SELECT invoices.InvoiceAmount, invoices.idInvoices, fundings.idfundings FROM invoices JOIN agencies ON invoices.idAgencies = agencies.idAgencies JOIN fundings ON agencies.idAgencies = fundings.IdAgencies WHERE processed = 0 AND fundings.FundingBalance > invoices.InvoiceAmount GROUP BY invoices.idInvoices`.  But what's that `GROUP BY` doing there?

Comment: @Eggyal I like what you're getting at. Also, you might have cleared another issue for me with the Group BY.

Comment: Oh, I completely overlooked your `group by`, that is a recipe for disaster in this query (you are not using any aggregate functions, and non-aggregate fields are effectively randomly chosen from associated values found); did you mean/want `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Answer (score 0):

I have this loop and insert every record that i need! Maybe you can modifiy or update yours loop with that!

```
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE ;
  DECLARE l_local_formato_retail_codigo,
  l_producto_sku,
  l_producto_descripcion_sra,
  l_producto_marca,
  l_producto_categoria VARCHAR (100) ;
  DECLARE l_precio DECIMAL (20, 7) DEFAULT 0 ;
  DECLARE l_un_1 INT (20) DEFAULT 0 ;
  DECLARE l_un_2 INT (20) DEFAULT 0 ;
  DECLARE l_clp_1 DECIMAL (20, 7) DEFAULT 0 ;
  DECLARE l_clp_2 DECIMAL (20, 7) DEFAULT 0 ;
  DECLARE contador INT DEFAULT 0 ;
  DECLARE valores CURSOR FOR 
  SELECT 
    local_formato_retail_codigo,
    producto_sku,
    producto_descripcion_sra,
    producto_marca,
    producto_categoria 
  FROM
    base_comercial 
  WHERE mes_fecha = fecha 
  GROUP BY producto_sku,
    local_formato_retail_codigo 
  ORDER BY local_formato_retail_codigo ASC,
    producto_sku ASC ;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE ;
  TRUNCATE precio_cd ;
  OPEN valores ;
  read_loop :
  LOOP
    FETCH valores INTO l_local_formato_retail_codigo,
    l_producto_sku,
    l_producto_descripcion_sra,
    l_producto_marca,
    l_producto_categoria ;
    IF done 
    THEN LEAVE read_loop ;
    END IF ;
    SET l_clp_1 = 
    (SELECT 
      ROUND(SUM(sellout_clp), 7) 
    FROM
      base_comercial 
    WHERE anno = DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%Y') 
      AND mes = DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%c') 
      AND local_formato_retail_codigo = l_local_formato_retail_codigo 
      AND producto_sku = l_producto_sku) ;
    SET l_clp_2 = 
    (SELECT 
      ROUND(SUM(sellout_clp), 7) 
    FROM
      base_comercial 
    WHERE anno = DATE_FORMAT(
        DATE_ADD(fecha, INTERVAL - 1 MONTH),
        '%Y'
      ) 
      AND mes = DATE_FORMAT(
        DATE_ADD(fecha, INTERVAL - 1 MONTH),
        '%c'
      ) 
      AND local_formato_retail_codigo = l_local_formato_retail_codigo 
      AND producto_sku = l_producto_sku) ;
    SET l_un_1 = 
    (SELECT 
      SUM(sellout_un) 
    FROM
      base_comercial 
    WHERE anno = DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%Y') 
      AND mes = DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%c') 
      AND local_formato_retail_codigo = l_local_formato_retail_codigo 
      AND producto_sku = l_producto_sku) ;
    SET l_un_2 = 
    (SELECT 
      SUM(sellout_un) 
    FROM
      base_comercial 
    WHERE anno = DATE_FORMAT(
        DATE_ADD(fecha, INTERVAL - 1 MONTH),
        '%Y'
      ) 
      AND mes = DATE_FORMAT(
        DATE_ADD(fecha, INTERVAL - 1 MONTH),
        '%c'
      ) 
      AND local_formato_retail_codigo = l_local_formato_retail_codigo 
      AND producto_sku = l_producto_sku) ;
    IF (ISNULL(l_clp_1)) 
    THEN SET l_clp_1 = 0 ;
    END IF ;
    IF (ISNULL(l_clp_2)) 
    THEN SET l_clp_2 = 0 ;
    END IF ;
    IF (ISNULL(l_un_1)) 
    THEN SET l_un_1 = 0 ;
    END IF ;
    IF (ISNULL(l_un_2)) 
    THEN SET l_un_2 = 0 ;
    END IF ;
    SET l_precio = ((l_clp_1 + l_clp_2) / (l_un_1 + l_un_2)) ;
    IF (ISNULL(l_precio)) 
    THEN SET l_precio = 0 ;
    END IF ;
    INSERT INTO precio_cd 
    VALUES
      (
        l_local_formato_retail_codigo,
        l_producto_sku,
        l_producto_descripcion_sra,
        l_producto_marca,
        l_producto_categoria,
        l_precio
      ) ;
  END LOOP read_loop ;
  CLOSE valores ;
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM
    precio_cd ;
```

Comment: I tried this, and it is still giving me an issue. I want to say there is something wrong with my code. Thank you, though!

Comment: I think you need close your loop.

END LOOP ze_loop ;

Comment: Still didn't do it. I think something else is off. Thanks though!